# Mouse click alternatives in plasma kde

Tags: kde, desktop-environment, plasma5

So am configuring a kde desktop and in a previous config, I had it set so that if someone left clicked on the desktop wallpaper it would drop a prompt to start an application, but I can't find that setting again on my current version of kde. Anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

right click on desktop → *Configure Desktop and Wallpaper* → *Mouse Actions*. Left mouse button is not there by default so just use the *Add Action* button to add action for left click (when prompted for input just left click on the button).

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That's it